# Send an email from SQL using the emails that result from a query

Tags: sql-server, email

I have a table that contains the order status and email address , If I do a select * statement this is my output

Name. Email Adress Approval code Order states. Qty tickets.

Juan Rivera. Juan @anyemail.com. Null. 1 50
Maria Rosales Maria @anyemail.com. 5567657. 1. 25 Jose Almonte. Jose@anyemail.com. Null. 1. 10

What I would like to do is run a stored procedure everynight and send an email to every user that has a null in the approval code, for example :

Dear : Jose ,

We noticed that your order does not contain an approval code , this order is scheduled to be canceled unless an approval code is entered in the next 72 hours.

Thanks you

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [SQL SERVER – 2008 – Configure Database Mail – Send Email From SQL Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Comment: Ronak ,  thanks but that doesn't answer my question . I am able to send email in the way your link explains but what I don't understand is how to email to all the email results after  running my query , or what the sp should look like . Basically if I have 5 results then I want to email all 5 results telling them that they have 72 hours to enter an estivation code . This sp would run every night

Comment: You need to create a procedure and in that loop through your result send and call the send mail procedure in that loop. So you can achieve what you want to do. Got it??

Comment: I've tried but it just doesn't make sense , I can send an email , that's not the problem , but I just can't figure out the proper query to run and loops against all the results that have a null in the approval code field